# Use Aeson's `genericToJSON` to encode a product type to an object, rather than a list

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

In the following code, `encoded` is equal to `{"FooBar":[{"Bar":4},{"Baz":2}]}`.

The desired encoding is `{"FooBar":{"Bar":4,"Baz":2}}`.

```
import           Data.Aeson
import           Data.Aeson.Types

data Foo = FooBar Bar Baz deriving Generic

newtype Bar = Bar Integer deriving Generic

newtype Baz = Baz Integer deriving Generic

instance ToJSON Foo where
  toJSON = genericToJSON options

instance ToJSON Bar where
  toJSON = genericToJSON options

instance ToJSON Baz where
  toJSON = genericToJSON options

options :: Options
options = defaultOptions { tagSingleConstructors = True, 
                           sumEncoding = ObjectWithSingleField }

foo :: Foo
foo = FooBar (Bar 4) (Baz 2)

encoded = encode foo
```

That is to say, I would like constructors of product types to be keys, and their components to be objects. I have been able to get pretty close with `tagSingleConstructors = True` and `sumEncoding = ObjectWithSingleField`, but Aeson puts `Bar` and `Baz` into a list rather that an object.

None of the other modifiers in `Options` seem to be relevant, but I may be missing something. Is the desired encoding possible with `genericToJSON`?

Answer (score 2):

Desired result can be achieved using record syntax.
In this case Aeson will encode value as an object.
However, two sets of options are needed in this case, one for `FooBar` and other for `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
data Foo = FooBar { bar:: Bar, baz :: Baz} deriving Generic

data Bar = Bar Integer deriving Generic

newtype Baz = Baz Integer deriving Generic
instance ToJSON Foo where
  toJSON = genericToJSON options

instance ToJSON Bar where
  toJSON = genericToJSON option_nested

instance ToJSON Baz where
  toJSON = genericToJSON option_nested

options :: Options
options = defaultOptions { tagSingleConstructors = True,
                           sumEncoding = ObjectWithSingleField,
                           fieldLabelModifier = \s -> (toUpper . head) s : (tail s)  }
option_nested :: Options
option_nested = defaultOptions { sumEncoding = UntaggedValue }
```

Result: `{"FooBar":{"Baz":2,"Bar":4}}"`

Comment: What if you have a sum type of product types? I suppose each product type could be a record but then you have partial accessors which will throw a runtime error if used on the wrong product type.

e.x. `data Foo = Bar { x :: String } | Baz { y :: String}` `x $ Baz "foo"`

will not throw any compile time warnings/errors but will result in a runtime error. This makes a strong case for not using records when you have a sum of products.